# Bizarre reoccurring GUID

Tags: windows

A google search for this guid shows that there are 1600 results.

```
9F4C2855-9F79-4B39-A8D0-E1D42DE1D5F3
```

I am currently working on a project that uses the Windows action center, and when I change this guid value, my project no longer works.

What is the significance of this guid in Windows?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391568(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130304-00/?p=5083